# SQL Merge Statement not working with Batch Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have created a stored procedure using MERGE statement as follows.

```
MERGE Tasks S
 USING (SELECT id, name, field1, field2, field3 FROM Tasks_Temp) SS
    ON S.id=SS.id
 WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET S.name=SS.name, S.field1=SS.field1, S.field2=SS.field2, S.field3=SS.field3
 WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (id, name, field1, field2, field3) VALUES (SS.id, SS.name, SS.field1, SS.field2, SS.field3)
```

**Tasks_temp:**

| id | name | field1 | field2 | field3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Task1 | NULL | NULL | STARTED |
| 2 | Task2 | SUBMITTED | NULL | STARTED |
| 1 | Task1 | SUBMITTED | NULL | STARTED |
| 3 | Task3 | NULL | NULL | STARTED |
| 1 | Task1 | APPROVED | NULL | STARTED |
| 2 | Task2 | APPROVED | NULL | STARTED |

**Tasks:(required)**

| id | name | field1 | field2 | field3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Task1 | APPROVED | NULL | STARTED |
| 2 | Task2 | APPROVED | NULL | STARTED |
| 3 | Task3 | NULL | NULL | STARTED |

Now here the `Tasks_Temp` table is empty at first and then it's filled with a sequential form of data as displayed where for each ID there's multiple changes like the field1, field2 or field3. The merge statement is inserting all the values into the other table, even duplicate IDs i.e., exactly the records as present in `Tasks_Temp`.

The next time when I run it gives me errors saying

> Trying to update multiple records not allowed

1. Is merge not able to handle batch data like this? Even if I ignore getting the latest data for each fields MERGE still inserts the same number of rows as present in `Tasks_Temp` table. If not, what are some other optimal approaches?
2. I feel that even if merge worked, it wouldn't necessarily mean it's taking the most updated field values for an id.
   However, if I have a timestamp provided, how can I insert the most recent records from the `Tasks_Temp` table to the `Tasks` table?

Comment: You have multiple tasks in your table `Tasks_temp` with the same `id`, which is your `JOIN` criteria; that's the problem. What value should `Tasks` be updated with? SQL Server doesn't know unless you tell it.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE Tasks_Temp(
   id     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,name   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  ,field1 VARCHAR(100)
  ,field2 VARCHAR(100)
  ,field3 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Tasks_Temp
(id,name,field1,field2,field3) VALUES 
(1,'Task1',NULL,NULL,'STARTED'),
(2,'Task2','SUBMITTED',NULL,'STARTED'),
(1,'Task1','SUBMITTED',NULL,'STARTED'),
(3,'Task3',NULL,NULL,'STARTED'),
(1,'Task1','APPROVED',NULL,'STARTED'),
(2,'Task2','APPROVED',NULL,'STARTED');
```

As @Larnu said you should use a criterion for choosing same id, based on my perspective it should be APPROVED>SUBMITTED>NULL for field1
hence I use `ROW_NUMBER` alphabetically and filter best values of `Tasks_temp` as follows:

```
SELECT id,
       NAME,
       field1,
       field2,
       field3
FROM   (SELECT id,
               NAME,
               field1,
               Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY NAME
                   ORDER BY IIF(field1 IS NULL, 'xxx', field1)) Stats,
               field2,
               field3
        FROM   tasks_temp) a
WHERE  stats = 1
```

That gives following table

| id | name | field1 | field2 | field3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Task1 | APPROVED | null | STARTED |
| 2 | Task2 | APPROVED | null | STARTED |
| 3 | Task3 | null | null | STARTED |

Hence you should use the above written query as a subquery for use with the `MERGE` in order to facilitate the operation:

```
MERGE Tasks S
 USING (SELECT id,
       NAME,
       field1,
       field2,
       field3
FROM   (SELECT id,
               NAME,
               field1,
               Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY NAME
                   ORDER BY Iif(field1 IS NULL, 'xxx', field1)) Stats,
               field2,
               field3
        FROM   tasks_temp) a
WHERE  stats = 1  ) SS
    ON S.id=SS.id
 WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET S.name=SS.name, S.field1=SS.field1, S.field2=SS.field2, S.field3=SS.field3
 WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (id, name, field1, field2, field3) VALUES (SS.id, SS.name, SS.field1, SS.field2, SS.field3)
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6PncLC-h)

Comment: Thanks! This helps a bit. But my main question is a bit different. This answers my second question. And here we are using only one field value (field1), this table actually has more than 20 columns which can each be changing in each entry in the temp table. However, from this approach I undestand that if I have a timestamp it can be solved.

Comment: My main question is suppose I don't take into account that it inserts the most recent data (APPROVED > SUBMITTED > NULL) shouldn't it at least not insert 
 duplicates? If it gets records one by one, it inserts the value and next time it finds the same ID it overwrites. That doesn't happen when the inner select statement is returning a batch of data which has duplicates. **Or does the MERGE statement's USING part work with unique records in a batch only (which you are doing here in the solution).**